# How would I play a separate GIF when a picture is clicked on?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I just started learning C# and I'm currently working on a simple Form application. What I wanted to do was when the GIF is clicked, it would switch to another GIF, and then back to the original after 1 second. But what is happening is nothing. It just stays the original GIF. If I try using message box's instead that works fine, its just trying to change the source of the GIF is the problem.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* pictureBox2.Show();
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       pictureBox2.Hide(); */
    pictureBox1.Image = WindowsLogin.Properties.Resources.PenguinEXE;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    pictureBox1.Image = WindowsLogin.Properties.Resources.PenguinIdle;
}
```

I've also tried using the `Show` and `Hide` method but that didn't work either.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` blocks the UI thread, so that it can't redraw anything. Use a timer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).

Mark your method as `async` and use `await Task.Delay(1000);` instead of `Thread.Sleep(1000);`

```
async private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = WindowsLogin.Properties.Resources.PenguinEXE;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    pictureBox1.Image = WindowsLogin.Properties.Resources.PenguinIdle;
}
```

Comment: To explain why this happens. Your click handler happens on the main thread by default. Doing a `Thread.Sleep` will sleep the main thread, which in turn sleeps your GUI. By marking the method as `async`, it will cause the method to be run on a separate thread, so that when you sleep it, the main thread will continue running.